# Scripts in sed - linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I got the concept of bash, now, I found a site full of riddles for practising bash. I solve a couple of scripts (you should mention what do they do, what they are missing or so, depends on the question) and I bumped this script:

```
random_var="$(echo $1 | sed -e 's/[^[:alnum:]]//g')"
```

Correct me if I'm wrong about my basic assumptions on the following code:

- $1 is the second argument that the script got (when the first is the script name)
- There is a pipeline between the second argument and the `sed` script that removes all alpha numerics and... according to what I understand, this script can be "broken" by using a delimiter such as `[/\]^$` and so ?

Now, there comes the difficulty (well, for me), the program gets an input from the user and, when the following script I just mention is found at a function returning true if the input is different than the result. I have no idea what is happening here, can someone enlighten me?

```
#!/bin/sh

func()
{
  somevar="$(echo $1 | sed -e 's/[^[:alnum:]]//g')"

  if [ "$somevar" != "$input" ] ; then
    return 1
  else
    return 0
  fi
}

# Sample usage of this function in a script

echo -n "Enter input: "
read input

if ! func "$input" ; then
  echo "HELL NO"
  exit 1
else
  echo "YES!"
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: `sed script that removes all alpha numerics` wrong. It removes all non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: It seems like you have an idea, since you explained it correctly with the exception of misinterpreting the regex, which happens, and @AvinashRaj has corrected you on. Where are you getting confused? It's tough to answer your question right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script tests a string to see whether it contains any non-alphanumeric characters.

As Avinash has mentioned in the comments, the sed command removes all non-alphanumeric characters. Within the function, `$input` has the same value as it does in the calling scope, which is also the same as the first argument, `$1`. This is perhaps a little bit confusing...

If `$somevar` is different to `$input` (`=$1`), then this means that sed has changed the string in some way. Therefore, the string must contain at least one non-alphanumeric character.

If the function returns 1 (there were some non-alphanumeric characters in the input), then `! func` is false, so the `else` branch will be executed and the script will return with an exit code of 0 (success). Otherwise, the script will return a non-zero exit code, indicating a failure.